# Execution of single JUnit test case in IntelliJ IDEA fails

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 11.1.1 (newest version as far as I know) on Windows XP, and for some reason I cannot run one single JUnit test case (method) within Idea.

When I run my entire unit test class every test comes out as "PASSED".

http://zone8.dk/stackoverflow/ideajunit1.png

However.. When i place the cursor inside one of the test case methods and hit CTRL+SHIFT+F10 to run this particular test case alone the test fails to execute.

http://zone8.dk/stackoverflow/ideajunit2.png

This is the entire IDEA console output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\java" -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7548 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.1\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\cygwin\home\jot\netbutikken\model\target\test-classes;C:\cygwin\home\jot\netbutikken\model\target\classes;C:\maven-repository\tapestry\tapestry\4.0.2\tapestry-4.0.2.jar;C:\maven-repository\jboss\javassist\3.0\javassist-3.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\maven-repository\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\1.1\commons-fileupload-1.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.jar;C:\maven-repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\ognl\ognl\2.6.7\ognl-2.6.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\oro\oro\2.0.8\oro-2.0.8.jar;C:\maven-repository\hivemind\hivemind\1.1.1\hivemind-1.1.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\hivemind\hivemind-lib\1.1.1\hivemind-lib-1.1.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2\1.5.1\axis2-1.5.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2-transport-local\1.5.1\axis2-transport-local-1.5.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2-kernel\1.5.1\axis2-kernel-1.5.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.8\axiom-api-1.2.8.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-activation_1.1_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec\1.2\geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.2.jar;C:\maven-repository\jaxen\jaxen\1.1.1\jaxen-1.1.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.8\axiom-impl-1.2.8.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\wstx-asl\3.2.4\wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.8\axiom-dom-1.2.8.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec\1.1.2\geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec\1.1\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.4\servlet-api-2.4.jar;C:\maven-repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\wsdl4j\wsdl4j\1.6.2\wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\ws\commons\schema\XmlSchema\1.4.3\XmlSchema-1.4.3.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\neethi\neethi\2.0.4\neethi-2.0.4.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\woden\woden-api\1.0M8\woden-api-1.0M8.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\ant\ant\1.7.0\ant-1.7.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\ant\ant-launcher\1.7.0\ant-launcher-1.7.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\xerces\xmlParserAPIs\2.6.0\xmlParserAPIs-2.6.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\woden\woden-impl-dom\1.0M8\woden-impl-dom-1.0M8.jar;C:\maven-repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.jar;C:\maven-repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.0\xalan-2.7.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.8.1\xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.3.03\xml-apis-1.3.03.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2-transport-http\1.5.1\axis2-transport-http-1.5.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.0\httpcore-4.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\axis\axis\1.4\axis-1.4.jar;C:\maven-repository\axis\axis-jaxrpc\1.4\axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar;C:\maven-repository\axis\axis-saaj\1.4\axis-saaj-1.4.jar;C:\maven-repository\axis\axis-wsdl4j\1.5.1\axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\commons-discovery\commons-discovery\0.2\commons-discovery-0.2.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.4.0\xmlbeans-2.4.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans-xpath\2.4.0\xmlbeans-xpath-2.4.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\net\sf\saxon\saxon\9\saxon-9.jar;C:\maven-repository\net\sf\saxon\saxon-dom\9\saxon-dom-9.jar;C:\maven-repository\net\sf\saxon\saxon-xpath\9\saxon-xpath-9.jar;C:\maven-repository\net\sf\saxon\saxon-s9api\9\saxon-s9api-9.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\hibernate\hibernate\3.2.7.ga\hibernate-3.2.7.ga.jar;C:\maven-repository\net\sf\ehcache\ehcache\1.2.3\ehcache-1.2.3.jar;C:\maven-repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\2.1.1\commons-collections-2.1.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.0.1B\jta-1.0.1B.jar;C:\maven-repository\asm\asm-attrs\1.5.3\asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar;C:\maven-repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.6\antlr-2.7.6.jar;C:\maven-repository\cglib\cglib\2.1_3\cglib-2.1_3.jar;C:\maven-repository\asm\asm\1.5.3\asm-1.5.3.jar;C:\maven-repository\dk\test\rosa\rosa-netbutikken\4.25.22\rosa-netbutikken-4.25.22.jar;C:\maven-repository\joda-time\joda-time\1.6\joda-time-1.6.jar;C:\maven-repository\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream\1.2.2\xstream-1.2.2.jar;C:\maven-repository\xpp3\xpp3_min\1.1.3.4.O\xpp3_min-1.1.3.4.O.jar;C:\maven-repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\maven-repository\velocity\velocity\1.4\velocity-1.4.jar;C:\maven-repository\velocity\velocity-dep\1.4\velocity-dep-1.4.jar;C:\maven-repository\commons-pool\commons-pool\1.5.4\commons-pool-1.5.4.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\fop\0.95\fop-0.95.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\xmlgraphics-commons\1.3.1\xmlgraphics-commons-1.3.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-svg-dom\1.7\batik-svg-dom-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-anim\1.7\batik-anim-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-awt-util\1.7\batik-awt-util-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-util\1.7\batik-util-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-dom\1.7\batik-dom-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-css\1.7\batik-css-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-ext\1.7\batik-ext-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\xml-apis\xml-apis-ext\1.3.04\xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-xml\1.7\batik-xml-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-parser\1.7\batik-parser-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-bridge\1.7\batik-bridge-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-gvt\1.7\batik-gvt-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-script\1.7\batik-script-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-transcoder\1.7\batik-transcoder-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-svggen\1.7\batik-svggen-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-extension\1.7\batik-extension-1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\avalon\framework\avalon-framework-api\4.3.1\avalon-framework-api-4.3.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\apache\avalon\framework\avalon-framework-impl\4.3.1\avalon-framework-impl-4.3.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\com\java4less\raztec\1.0\raztec-1.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\com\java4less\rbarcode\1.0\rbarcode-1.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0\guice-3.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\maven-repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\easymock\easymock\3.0\easymock-3.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.2\cglib-nodep-2.2.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\1.2\objenesis-1.2.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\jmock\jmock-legacy\2.2.0\jmock-legacy-2.2.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\jmock\jmock\2.2.0\jmock-2.2.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.1\hamcrest-core-1.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.1\hamcrest-library-1.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\com\googlecode\juniversalchardet\juniversalchardet\1.0.3\juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar;C:\maven-repository\ojdbc\ojdbc\14\ojdbc-14.jar;C:\maven-repository\hsqldb\hsqldb\1.8.0.7\hsqldb-1.8.0.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\com\lowagie\itext\2.1.7\itext-2.1.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\bouncycastle\bcmail-jdk14\138\bcmail-jdk14-138.jar;C:\maven-repository\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk14\138\bcprov-jdk14-138.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\bouncycastle\bctsp-jdk14\1.38\bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk14\1.38\bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\bouncycastle\bcmail-jdk14\1.38\bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar;C:\maven-repository\info\cukes\cucumber-java\1.0.0\cucumber-java-1.0.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\info\cukes\cucumber-core\1.0.0\cucumber-core-1.0.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\info\cukes\gherkin\2.9.3\gherkin-2.9.3.jar;C:\maven-repository\info\cukes\cucumber-html\0.2.1\cucumber-html-0.2.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\info\cukes\cucumber-junit\1.0.0\cucumber-junit-1.0.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\info\cukes\cucumber-guice\1.0.0\cucumber-guice-1.0.0.jar;C:\maven-repository\junit\junit\4.7\junit-4.7.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.6.1\jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.6.1\slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.6.1\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar;C:\maven-repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.16\log4j-1.2.16.jar;C:\maven-repository\dk\test\log4j\testLog4jSetup\0.1\testLog4jSetup-0.1.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 dk.test.salg.netbutikken.model.handlers.TestRejseSoegningEventHandler,testPerformMedEnkeltRejse

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any IDEA's anyone? :) I feel like I've searched the entire web for an answer.
Thank you very much in advance!

I should probably emphasize that the test content doesn't matter at all. I have tried to run many different test cases this way in different modules and projects.

Comment: I've seen something similar before with a different java testing framework and the problem was that the test was exiting the application. But the handler for running multiple tests displayed the results as a lack of failure IE passing. It is a longshot but worth considering.

Comment: It sure is! However.. None of the test cases in the example do exit the application - and, as I said, the same thing happens for every single test class I've tried so far. It might be a thread problem though. I don't know how JUnit attaches itself inside IDEA.

Comment: Does it help if you update your JUnit dependency to `4.10` version?

Comment: Unfortunately no. My Maven dependency was set to 4.7, but changing it to 4.10 made no difference. However downgrading to 4.4 or so made the environment execute all test cases at all times, disregarding the run configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a known issue: [IDEA-84031](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84031). The fix will be available in IDEA 11.1.2 release.

Comment: Thanks! From the link you provided I don't see an issue fix on the IDEA roadmap? However the workaround provided works fine. (Yes, I use JUnit 3 syntax apparently, i.e. no @test-annotations). If I set VM-parameter: -Didea.force.junit3=true, everything works.